# UML partial ordering in Sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

with regard to sequence diagram and exactly in partial ordering 
I read the following sentence but i didn't understand the exact meaning of it :

> "interactions are only partially ordered"

What this sentence means??

Answer (score 1):

This means in a sequence diagram not all operations are done right interactievely ordered! A familiar real-life example of a partially ordered set is a collection of people ordered by genealogical descendancy. Some pairs of people bear the ancestor-descendant relationship, but other pairs bear no such relationship.

Comment: .Do you mean that `not all operations` run in sequential manner ?